# How to convert string to JSON in Go?

Tags: json, go

Let’s say I have this string:

```golang
`
{
    "testCode": 0,
    "replyTest": "OK",
    "data": {
        "001": {
            "fields": {
                "name": "arben",
                "fav_color": "blue",
                "address": "PH",
            }
        },
        "002": {
            "fields": {
                "name": "john",
                "fav_color": "black",
                "address": "PH",
            }
        },
    }
}
`
```

How to convert this string to JSON where `data` is in form of list in order for me to loop this list in a process?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Comment: That string _is_ JSON. Do you mean you want to convert it to some Go data structure?

Comment: yes i want this string to convert to GO data structure

Comment: A simple enough task with _plenty_ of examples all over the web. What have you tried and how did it not work?

Comment: `json.Unmarshal`

Comment: having a hardtime structuring the `"data"` part

Comment: ￼@ArbenJohnAvillanosa Questions seeking debugging help (__"why isn't this code working?"__) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it __in the question itself__. Questions without __a clear problem statement__ are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39914425/13860

Comment: For starters: this string is not valid JSON. The trailing `,` after the address value is not a valid token.

Comment: There are several trailing  commas that make this invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have json property names that aren't known upfront, or they don't lend themselves very well to be represented as fields of a struct then you're left more or less with one option, a map. So first you need to unmarshal the `"data"` property into a map.

However maps in Go are implemented as **unordered** groups of elements indexed by a set of unique keys. So basically there's no way to *ensure* the order of a map in Go, and therefore you'll have to transfer the data from the map into something that can be ordered, like a slice for example.

After you've got your data in the slice you can use the standard [`sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package to sort the slice in the order you want.

---

You can start by declaring the types you need:

```
type DataItem struct {
    Key    string     `json:"-"`
    Fields DataFields `json:"fields"`
}

type DataFields struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    FavColor string `json:"fav_color"`
    Address  string `json:"address"`
}
```

Then unmarshal the json

```
var obj struct {
    TestCode  int                  `json:"testCode"`
    ReplyTest string               `json:"replyTest"`
    Data      map[string]*DataItem `json:"data"`
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Transfer the contents of the map into a slice

```
items := []*DataItem{}
for key, item := range obj.Data {
    item.Key = key // keep track of the key because it will be used to order the contents of the slice
    items = append(items, item)
}
```

Finally sort the slice

```
sort.Slice(items, func(i, j int) bool {
    return items[i].Key < items[j].Key
})
```

https://play.golang.com/p/D2u46veOQwD

Comment: While this code does the required things, I would like to point out to any reader that using values (`"001"` and `"002"` in OP's sample) as keys is ***VERY*** bad practice.  `data` should be an array of objects, which could easily hold the required values like `"data":[{"number":"001","name":"arben","fav_color":"blue","address": "PH"},...]`.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg In my defense, I've answered the question under the assumption that that is some json OP needs to process but over whose structure they don't have control. And I agree that in general it would be considered bad practice, however the provider of the json may have their reasons... so whatever, the correct naming of json properties wasn't part of the question. That said, qualifying it as "very" in all caps, bold, and italic might a bit too dramatic ;), if a project fails it's probably not because of their json properties.

Comment: No attack on your solution at all, Sir, all on the data model at hand. But I somehow disagree on the project failing. It may not be *because* of the JSON property, but a sloppy data model usually indicates a certain... laziness when it comes to basics.

Comment: Agree with you there, not *because* but as indicator of some larger issue. And btw, even though I did use "In my defense", I did not take your comment as an attack, Sir ;), I just wanted to add a slightly different take on the matter, that's all.